# What is the difference between display:none and setting the height and width equal to 0 of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If we want to make an element disappeared from the page completely, we could use the CSS property value `display:none`

Alternatively we can effectively hide an element with `visibility:hidden` but that element would still take the space as if it were there which I don't want.

So, If I want to actually hide an element without using the `display:none`, I see an option of explicitly setting the `width` and `height` equal to `0` of the element.

What is the semantic difference between these two ?

Comment: What is your reasoning for avoiding display:none?

Comment: It smells like a SEO question?

Comment: why do you want to use of `width` and `height` equal to 0 if there is css `display:none` property is available? is there any reason behind it?

Comment: It probably depends on the browser implementation...

Answer (score 5):

An element with no height or width still has a margin and/or border and will still influence surrounding elements by its presence in the tree, e.g. with float and clear rules. Only an element with `display: none` is really truly *not present*.

Comment: Let's say except height and width, it has no other property set. Is it really present there ?

Comment: Yes, it's still *present*. If the element has two siblings, it will prevent their borders collapsing, for instance.

Comment: Interesting enough !

Comment: BTW, I meant *margins collapsing* above, not borders...

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` takes the element out of the page, so screen readers can't see it. if you want to completely remove the element from the dom you should use `display: none` otherwise this does the same thing.

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The display property tells the browser how to show an element. Display:none means that the element will not appear on the page at all. There will be no space allocated it. it will be hidden. But if you give height and width as 0px; then in this case, the contents will appear and contents will overflow outside the div.